# what's the difference between (728,) and (1,728) in numpy shape?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

These two seem both array to me.

```
# suppose that test_data has [1000,728] shape 
print (test_data[0:1,:].shape)
# output [1,728]
print (test_data[0,:].shape)
# output [728,]
```

I tried these two arrays in keras sequential `model.predict_classes(x)` function.
The test_data[0:1,:] works but test_data[0,:] gives error.

Comment: What is the `dtype` ?

Comment: Code in title, does not match code in body.

Comment: Check the `keras` documentation to see what expects.

Comment: I glanced at the `keras` doc for that function.  It's vague about the required dimensions.  Which means you/we need a more basic understanding of what `keras` expects across the board.  I can explain the shape differences from a `numpy` perspective, but that won't help if `keras` has specific expectations.

Comment: @hpaulj I think that keras model.predict_classes(x) function expects an "array of array" argument of x